# Why do I get a TypeError when I try to create a data frame?

Tags: python, pandas

I am writing code to analyze some data and want to create a data frame. How do I set it up successfully to run?

this is for analysis of data and I would like to create a data frame that can categorize data in different grades such as `A`
Here is the code I wrote:

```
import analyze_lc_Feb2update
from imp import reload 
analyze_lc_Feb2update = reload(analyze_lc_Feb2update)
df = analyze_lc_Feb2update.create_df()
df.shape
df_new = df[df.grade=='A']
df_new.shape
df.columns
df.int_rate.head(5)
df.int_rate.tail(5)
df.int_rate.dtype
df.term.dtype
df_new = df[df.grade =='A']
df_new.shape
```

output:

```
TypeError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-7079435f776f> in <module>()
2 from imp import reload
3 analyze_lc_Feb2update = reload(analyze_lc_Feb2update)
4 df = analyze_lc_Feb2update.create_df()
5 df.shape
6 df_new = df[df.grade=='A']

TypeError: create_df() missing 1 required positional 
argument: 'grade'
```

Comment: can you share your input and expected output

Answer (score 0):

Based on what was provided I guess your problem is here:

```
from imp import reload 
analyze_lc_Feb2update = reload(analyze_lc_Feb2update)
df = analyze_lc_Feb2update.create_df()
```

This looks like some custom library you are trying to use, of which the .create_df() method requires a positional argument "grade" which would require you to do something like:

```
df = analyze_lc_Feb2update.create_df(grade="blah")
```